# Change 'font size' inside <p>according to text length - Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a `<p>` that contains text that generates with `*ngIf` (the data coming from the back-end). **I want to change the text size** according to the text-length. I tried to import the `<p>`  with the help of `@ViewChild`
to manipulate the element, but it giving me `undefined`.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Html

```
 <section class="movies-container">
        <div class="movies-container__box" *ngFor="let m of movies">
            <img class="movies-container__box__img" src="{{m.movieImg}}" alt="">
            <p #movieName  class="movies-container__box__title" >{{m.movieName}} 
            </p>
            <a class="user-button">View Details</a>
        </div>
 </section>
```

Ts

```
export class UserInterfaceComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild ('movieName' , {read: ElementRef}) movieName: ElementRef;


  private movieListSub: Subscription;
  private movies: UserMovie[] = []


  constructor( private movieService: UserMovieService,
               private myElement: ElementRef ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.movieListSub = this.movieService.getUpdatedMovieList().subscribe(response => {
      this.movies = response.userMovieList;
    })
    console.log(this.movieName)
  }
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @fatemefazli done!

Comment: Since you use a *ngFor over the code i would assume you have ViewChildren instead of ViewChild? https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren. Further i assume your data is coming asynchronous? so when you call this.moveName the data is not arrived and futher not rendered. If you want to change your text-size on a fixed text length you can just go in the subscription over each element and define it? Than you don't need viewchildren at all.

Comment: since you have more elements use ```ViewChildren``` and also log the ```this.movieName``` in ```ngAfterViewInit(){}``` .

Comment: check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfjnzz).

Comment: if it helped you, will post it as answer.

Comment: @Krosan, Can you give me a direction how to do it?

Comment: @fatemefazli, Well the comment does explain why i didn't saw the element in the console, but  @krosan is right, I should define the `text -size` inside the subscription.

Comment: @fatemefazli make a public variable for example myFontSize (also set a default one). iterate inside your subscription overall elements and calculate the fontSize you want and set in on myFontSize. In the template bind the font size on the element. I think its [style.font-size.px]="myFontSize" (but you might have to check if it is font-size). hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick all inside the DOM by giving your `<p>` an hashtag `#myTxt`.
After this, you can call it inside the DOM.
Add the `[ngStyle]` property to the `<p>` element and evaluate its value by getting myTxt.innerHTML.length

```
[ngStyle]="{'font-size': myTxt.innerHTML.length+'px'}"
```

This should scale the Text according to its length.

Keep in mind, that DOM-logic should generally be avoided but if needed keep it as short and easy as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't work its creating a mass with the text size  on resize.